# AngularJs and ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I have just started learning AngularJS but I am stuck at this point. I made three files in one project:

```
1.Index.html
2.Angular.min.js( downloaded from official site)
3.Script.js
```

But when I am opening html in browser I am not getting the value of test property. It just shows the `{{test}}` (not the value). Will be very thankful if you help me out.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app = "myapp">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body  ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
           {{test}}
           <script src = "angular.min.js"</script>
           <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>***
```

Script.js file is

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.test = "Welcome to my world";

}]);
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with code. Make sure the javascript files are being loaded correctly.

Comment: Check the developer tools (F12 in Chrome, Firefox and Opera) and see if the console displays any errors, because your code doesn't have any.

Comment: @GuranjanSingh: Yes it is loaded correctly, but no luck.

Comment: @Skaparate: console showing this error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr],

Comment: @GagandeepSingh I'm certain the problem is with loading of the library. [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jEqwkP?p=info) is a plunker with the same code. Only difference is I'm loading the angular library from the google CDN and it works. Also, as mentioned in the answer you were missing `>` from the script tag where you include the library. That will cause it to break as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check the network tab be sure angular itself is actually loading copying and pasting your code into a running sample.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.test = "Welcome to my world";

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app = "myapp">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body  ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
           {{test}}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
           <!--
           you were missing a > here
           <script src = "angular.min.js"</script>
           <script src = "script.js"></script>
-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but no luck. Also, yes angular file has been loaded into my sample.